# How can I get the current lesson, given a collection of lesson time ranges in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, time, range

I am making a timetabling program using Windows Forms and C# for a school.

The school uses an API that returns a JSON object containing a list of lessons.

Provided in the information for each lesson, there is the time slot for that lesson, in the form;

`hh:mm - hh:mm` (24h format).

**I need to find the current lesson**, given the lesson slot times and the current time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Are you interested in how to convert JSON to C#, if not that's not relevant to the question, remove it. Figure out if you are stuck on parsing a range, parsing hh:mm, finding out whether a time lies in a given range, ... and post just that question and just that code / sample data. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a lot of missing pieces from your question, but if you want to parse a time in a specific format, you'd use `DateTime.ParseExact`. Here is an example based on a 24 hour clock:

```
// 24 hour clock. If this is a 12 hour clock, use the format "hh:mm"
var startTime = DateTime.ParseExact("08:44", "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var endTime = DateTime.ParseExact("14:22", "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var timeToTest = DateTime.Now;

if((timeToTest >= startTime) && (timeToTest <= endTime))
{
    Console.WriteLine("We are currently in range.");
}
```

Keep in mind that the `DateTime` returned by `ParseExact` will be of the day it was generated, since no day/month/year was used to calculate it.

Comment: For anyone else wanting to use this, `CultureInfo` uses `System.Globalization`.